# solicit-response pattern implementation in JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

Is there a way to implement solicit-response pattern with JAX-WS? I would be really nice alternative to long-pooling or websockets, but I cannot find any information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently according to JAX-WS specification (JAX-WS) 2.2 Rev a Section 2.3:

> Mapping of notification and solicit-response operations is out of scope.

None of major JAX-WS frameworks (CXF, Metro, Axis2) supports solicit-response.

Frankly speaking solicit-response MEP is quite a blurry idea. Technically I wonder how clients should be sign up for notifications (solicitations). It is also not part of WS Basic Profile, [which states](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-2_0%28WGD%29.html#Allowed_Operations):

> Solicit-Response and Notification operations are not well defined by WSDL 1.1; furthermore, WSDL 1.1 does not define bindings for them.

You didn't specify what do you need solicit-response MEP for.

If you need some asynchrony you could use asynchronous client calls (polling or callback approach). More about that can be found in [JAX-WS tutorial](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.8/docs/ch03.html#users-guide-asynchronous-client). You can use it together with JMS transport in order to avoid HTTP timeouts.

However, using this approach you cannot implement notifications of multiple clients effectively. If you need notifications maybe JMS topics would be useful.